# How to overwrite a commit with detached HEAD commit?

Tags: git

I have a branch that looks like this

```
---A-----------B
    \
     \
      C (Detached HEAD)
```

I got it by this process:

```
git checkout branch
git checkout HEAD~
git commit -m "C"
```

and I want `C` to overwrite `B` (discard all changes in B)

Best would be without merging temp branch because I want the branch graph to look as simple as possible

Comment: Track down C's sha1, `git checkout branch; git reset Csha1 --hard`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Force delete the `branch` and create branch on the `C` commit. Do force push if branch is in any remote repository.

If you can repeate the commit (i.e. you have a diff saved somewhere), you can reset branch's `HEAD` to `HEAD~` and then do the commit.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout <C>

git branch -D branch

git checkout -b branch
```

Your graph will become:

```
---A-----C <== branch
    \
     \---B
```

If B is already in the remote repository, use "git push -f" to force the push. B will be garbage collected in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git checkout sha1ofcommittokeep

git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD:branchtooverwrite
```